# How use binding in template with datasource?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-mvvm

I have observable model with a function and datasource.

I cant use the function in template by datasource.

http://dojo.telerik.com/oHoxI

Comment: you should add the relevant part of the code to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A kendo.data.DataSource is not an array; the correct API method is [`add`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-add):

```
dataSource.add(...);
```

([demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@lhoeppner/oJoge))

same problem:

```
this.get("products") // this is not an array, yet you treat it like one
```

if you want to get the data, use the DataSource.data() method:

```
this.get("products").data()
```

Comment: I don't understand. data-bind on click on template don't work. in my code and with remote datasource

Comment: I use listview controll

Comment: see edit - you need to check all places that use the DS incorrectly